# In Drupal 8 Webform_Civicrm how do I clone a Contact?

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-8

Running Drupal and Webform_civicrm 8.x-5.0-beta4.
How do I clone a Contact?

If I create one Contact, then change the number of Contacts from 1 to 2 (or more) I get the message:

```
Tip: Consider using the clone feature to add multiple similar contacts. (more info)
```

The (more info) looks like a link, but does nothing when I click it.
On D7 there is a 'Clone Contact' link on the Webform tab, but I can't find the equivalent on the D8 Build tab, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such clone feature yet. We've had to park it for now as other outstanding bugs: re: existing contact element, and re: static/live options take precedence.

So I've just removed the Tip (for now) and have added a ToDo statement:
https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/449

Comment: That's fine, thanks.